# Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I'm getting error`Error: Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators` when i try to use `allowDiskUse` in aggregation pipeline.I followed the structure of Mongodb website but still failed, why?

```
coin.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                exchange: exchange
            }
        },
        {
            $unwind: "$coin_sum"
        },
        {
            // match query with array (here is no longer array)
            $match: {
                $or: [
                    { "coin_sum.granularity": "minute", "coin_sum.timeStamp": { $lt: (expiration.minute) ? parseInt(timeStamp) - expiration.minute : 0 } },
                    { "coin_sum.granularity": "hour", "coin_sum.timeStamp": { $lt: (expiration.hour) ? parseInt(timeStamp) - expiration.hour : 0 } },
                    { "coin_sum.granularity": "day", "coin_sum.timeStamp": { $lt: (expiration.day) ? parseInt(timeStamp) - expiration.day : 0 } },
                    { "coin_sum.granularity": "month", "coin_sum.timeStamp": { $lt: (expiration.month) ? parseInt(timeStamp) - expiration.month : 0 } }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: "$exchange",
                remove_coins: {
                    $addToSet: {
                        high: "$coin_sum.high",
                        low: "$coin_sum.low"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ], 
    { 
        allowDiskUse: true, 
        cursor: { 
            batchSize: 1000 
        }
    }).then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
    });
```

Comment: When you add `cursor` to the options the `.aggregate()` does not return a `Promise` but instead returns a `Cursor`. So this should be `var cursor = coin.aggregate(...); cusor.on( data => { ... }); or similar to iterate a cursor, or you simply don't  use `cursor` in the "options" at all. You probably did this because you got an error about "memory exceeded", which is usually complaining that you should be narrowing your selection with an "index", rather than going straight to a 'cursor' as your "go to".\

Comment: The largest problem an likely cause of such a "memory exceeded" error is that you don't have indexes, and that like here your "array" items really should be selected for matches with `$elemMatch` **"before"** you process with `$unwind`. Otherwise those conditions "filtering" the array are actually processing more documents than they need to be, and you exceed memory as a result.

Comment: Not sure exactly how that ? operator stuff is going to resolve in your environment.   Try cutting out everything except the first match in the pipeline and keep the options object (arg 2, allowDiskUse, etc.).   Then add things back in add see where the error pops in.

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti Already told them why. Adding `cursor` to the options and returning a `Promise` is not supported and mongoose is getting confused at providing both the "options" block as well as asking for a return Promise. You cannot do "both".

Comment: I see.  Probably good to make that an actual answer then, no?

Comment: @NeilLunn Hi there, can you explain me more about the indexes? For example in this case the indexes would be `{exchange : 1} `?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out

```
 coin.aggregate(
        {
            $match: {
                exchange: exchange
            }
        },
        {
            $unwind: "$coin_sum"
        },
        {
            $match: {
                $or: [
                    { "coin_sum.granularity": "minute", "coin_sum.timeStamp": { $lt: (expiration.minute) ? parseInt(timeStamp) - expiration.minute : 0 } },
                    { "coin_sum.granularity": "hour", "coin_sum.timeStamp": { $lt: (expiration.hour) ? parseInt(timeStamp) - expiration.hour : 0 } },
                    { "coin_sum.granularity": "day", "coin_sum.timeStamp": { $lt: (expiration.day) ? parseInt(timeStamp) - expiration.day : 0 } },
                    { "coin_sum.granularity": "month", "coin_sum.timeStamp": { $lt: (expiration.month) ? parseInt(timeStamp) - expiration.month : 0 } }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: "$exchange",
                remove_timeStamp: {
                    $addToSet: "$coin_sum.timeStamp"
                },
                remove_granularity: {
                    $addToSet: "$coin_sum.granularity"
                }
            }
        }
    ).allowDiskUse(true).cursor({batchSize : 1000})
        .then((res) => { //do something });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
coin.aggregate(
        { "$facet": {
            {
                $match: {
                    exchange: exchange
                }
            },
            {
                $unwind: "$coin_sum"
            },
            {
                $match: {
                    $or: [
                        { "coin_sum.granularity": "minute", "coin_sum.timeStamp": 
                        { $lt: (expiration.minute) ? parseInt(timeStamp) - 
                          expiration.minute : 0 } },
                        { "coin_sum.granularity": "hour", "coin_sum.timeStamp": { 
                           $lt: (expiration.hour) ? parseInt(timeStamp) - 
                            expiration.hour : 0 } },
                        { "coin_sum.granularity": "day", "coin_sum.timeStamp": { 
                           $lt: (expiration.day) ? parseInt(timeStamp) - 
                            expiration.day : 0 } },
                        { "coin_sum.granularity": "month", "coin_sum.timeStamp": { 
                           $lt: (expiration.month) ? parseInt(timeStamp) - 
                           expiration.month : 0 } }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: "$exchange",
                    remove_timeStamp: {
                        $addToSet: "$coin_sum.timeStamp"
                    },
                    remove_granularity: {
                        $addToSet: "$coin_sum.granularity"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        ).allowDiskUse(true).cursor({batchSize : 1000})
            .then((res) => { //do something });
```

Comment: Might be worthwhile explaining how your solution fixed the issue before the code. Thanks for helping out and welcome to Stack Overflow.